# Windows 11 automatically lowers volume on Groove Music / Windows Media Player

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11

I have a problem after upgrading to windows 11 where Groove Music / Windows Media Player / Windows Media Player Legacy automatically lowers the volume of **some** of my music. The issue is not speaker specific, and it doesn't exist on my 3rd party media player apps (itunes, spotify, potplayer). What I've tried so far:

- Disabling all enhancements for all speakers both in settings and in control panel Hardware & Sound menu, including setting the communications tab to "Do nothing" when a call is detected
- Reinstalling the audio driver
- Disabling audio settings on manufacturer bundlewares (Dolby Atmos for Gaming, Lenovo Vantage, Realtek Audio Console)
- Setting up a windows sandbox and installed Groove Music there (issue still persists)

I've created a video for reference [here](https://streamable.com/big5dk), where the issue affected the first song, but not the second one

Comment: Could be anything. I know drivers/software for my onboard audio (realtek) has a "Loudness Equalization" option that messes with volumes

Comment: I end up going back to windows 10 because I practically ran out of audio option in my PC to fiddle with and everything is normal now